# How to enable the new Objective-C object literals on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

When I create a new project with Xcode 4.4 and add these lines:

```
NSDictionary *test = @{ @"key" : @"test value" };
NSString *value = test[@"key"];
NSLog(@"value is: %@", value);
```

it compiles with no warnings and executes as expected.

Adding the same lines to an existing project produces the compiler error:

```
NSString *value = test[@"key"]; <-- Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *'
```

I compared both projects' target build settings but nothing leapt out at me.

**Update:**
The new project that successfully compiled was for OSX. I tried another new one for iOS with the above lines and it fails to compile, same as my pre-existing (iOS) project.

Comment: And both projects were using clang 4.0?

Comment: @trojanfoe Both using "Apple LLVM compiler 4.0".

Comment: And both target x86_64 (not i386)?

Comment: Hmm... the one that compiles is targeting OSX (i386 x86_64) and the one that fails iOS (armv6 armv7). Arm LLVM compiler doesn't support the new object literals?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to work. "All of these new language features require the modern Objective-C runtime.  This runtime is used on all architectures for iOS, and 64-bit x86 (x86_64) on the Mac.  These features are not supported when targetting i386 on the Mac."

Comment: I just created a fresh iOS project, pasted the above lines in, and it fails to compile.

Comment: I haven't seen any examples on the use of the syntax `test[@"key"]`.  Where did you see that?

Comment: In http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html, Object Subscripting section.

Comment: The XCode 4.4's what new did mention that these literals only applies to apps on OSX, not iOS

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This has nothing to do with old vs. new project, but rather is a factor of the SDK you use. The problem you're running into is that while this is a compiler feature, it requires SDK support. The iOS 5 SDK does not provide that support, though the iOS 6 SDK does.

For that reason, now you should just use the iOS 6 SDK. Read on if you want to use object subscripting with the iOS 5 SDK.

All you need to do is add a header file so that the compiler will try the call. There's no need to add an implementation; it's handled automatically by `arclite`. (If you are not using ARC, you will have to force the linker to include `arclite`. But you still don't have to actually switch to it.)

Create a new interface file, **NSObject+subscripts.h**.

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 60000
@interface NSDictionary(subscripts)
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key;
@end

@interface NSMutableDictionary(subscripts)
- (void)setObject:(id)obj forKeyedSubscript:(id <NSCopying>)key;
@end

@interface NSArray(subscripts)
- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
@end

@interface NSMutableArray(subscripts)
- (void)setObject:(id)obj atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
@end
#endif
```

I've put this chunk on [github](https://github.com/tewha/iOS-Subscripting).

Note: I used to suggest adding the required methods to `NSObject` before explaining how to add them only to the relevant objects. In retrospect, I believe this was an error on my part; it led to errors being caught at runtime rather than compile time, unlike the approach now presented here. That approach is still on my [blog](http://tewha.net/2012/08/modern-objective-c-with-ios-5/), but I now believe it to be more of a cool hack than a useful approach.

Source:

- [Peter Steinberger, Using Subscripting With Xcode 4.4 and iOS 4.3+](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2012/using-subscripting-with-Xcode-4_4-and-iOS-4_3/)

Comment: That did the job for me, thanks! It'll be fine until Xcode 4.5 ships with the official iOS support.

Comment: I only added it on NSDictionary / NSArray and implemented it to call the regular methods.  It works just fine (that's what ios 6 does anyway).

Comment: You don't need an @implementation. But yeah, today I had no problem adding just the categories I needed to just the classes I wanted. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Anyone have any idea how Apple would feel about this in an app submission? As I understand it, ARClite actually adds the necessary implementations itself, so from Apple's point of view the methods `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` etc are not undocumented private methods but user-defined methods, correct?

Comment: Correct. You're making calls to arclite. I haven't gone through App Review yet, but there's no other point to Apple putting those swizzles in arclite than for us to use them.

Comment: how to force the linker to include arclite?

Comment: Turn on ARC in the target's build settings.

Comment: To clarify, you saying that in order to use literals in a non-arc project, I must turn on arc and put the linker flags on all my files to not use arc? This does not sound efficient.

Comment: No, just turn on ARC for the linker only. I used to know how to do this, but don't anymore. Sorry. :) I think it might have been OTHER_LDFLAGS.

Comment: Also even using a newer SDKs will give you problems on iOS 5 if you try to use subscripting from a class' `+(void)load` method! It seems that arclite is not yet loaded at that time.