# Is objectAtIndexedSubscript available in IOS5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

The documentation says it's available in MacOS 1.08.

So what's the story? What about for iOS5?

It's a very important selector because self[5] will actually turn into [self objectAtIndexedSubscript:5] unless I am missing something.

Doesn't work in NSOrderedSet but works in NSArray.

What am I missing?

Comment: The NSArray docs state that `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` was added in iOS 6 but the subscript syntax works with iOS 5.x. Very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, only since iOS 6 unfortunately.

Apple has separate documentations for the OS X and the iOS APIs. You have to check the right one: [`objectAtIndexedSubscript:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndexedSubscript%3a).

> **Availability** 
>  
>   Available in iOS 6.0 and later.

Comment: Despite the `NSArray` docs stating this, the `someArray[index]` syntax does work with iOS 5.x. But the same syntax crashes at runtime under iOS 5.x using an `NSOrderedSet`.

Comment: That's because when compiling, `someArray[index]` will actually be transformed into `[someArray objectAtIndex:index]`. This new syntax is a compiler feature and available since Xcode 4.4. Only since iOS 6 however can you override `objectAtIndexedSubscript:`. I'm not sure, but I think `NSOrderedSet` doesn't support the bracket index syntax.

Comment: I understand what the compiler is doing with the new syntax. I just thought it translated the subscript syntax to the `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` method. I added that method to one of my own classes and this allows me to use the subscript syntax with my custom class.

Comment: DrummerB is incorrect about what's happening. What's actually happening is that the compiler is quietly inserting a category on relevant classes adding -objectAtIndexedSubscript:, if your deployment target is iOS 5.

Comment: maddy has it right. And Apple's docs are wrong. The ARCLite library, automatically linked to all projects that have ARC enabled (since Xcode 4.2, I believe), includes the `objectAtIndexedSubscript:`, etc., implementations for arrays and dictionaries. This works at least back to iOS 5 (and probably 4, but I haven't tested or found any definitive references).

Comment: Just to correct my previous comment, it looks like subscript syntax wasn't supported until LLVM 4.0, in Xcode 4.4/4.5, so that's likely when the ARCLite library picked up the required methods to support subscripting.

Answer (score 7):

While `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` is not available previous to iOS 6, `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`subscripting **is** available. That means that you can use syntax like this:

```
myArray[2] = @"thingie";
myDictionary[@"roger"] = @"barry";
```

And [it will deploy back to iOS 4](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/).

However `NSOrderedSet` subscripting **will not** work on iOS 5 and previous. For that, you will need to provide a category that redirects `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` calls to `objectAtIndex:`.

Addendum: Apple's docs for `NSMutableOrderedSet` are also incorrect. It states that index subscripting does an insert, when in reality is does a replace (as one would expect).

Comment: The link says it deploys back to iOS 5 not iOS 4. But great find!

Comment: Yeah, the docs say iOS 5, but ARClite works with iOS 4, so I'm not sure which is right. I haven't tested, and probably few care at this point, but for the sake of historical accuracy, it would be nice to know.

Comment: Also, [Steven Fisher's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11659848/686385) to a related question describes how to use the subscript syntax while building against the iOS 5 (and maybe iOS 4) SDK.

Answer (score 1):

If you need your code to run on iOS 5, you'll need to replace

```
myOrderedSetOfHilariousAcronyms[2] = @"ROFL";
```

with

```
[myOrderedSetOfHilariousAcronyms setObject:@"ROFL" atIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 0):

I look at the NSOrderedSet.h file and I saw this:

```
- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx NS_AVAILABLE(10_8, 6_0);
```

So it doesn't work for IOS5.