# Aviary SDK issue with iOS 5.0 - objectAtIndexedSubscript

Tags: iphone, ios, aviary

I have downloaded the latest Aviary code 2.6.0 and incorporated it in my Xcode 4.2 for my iPhone 4S running iOS 5.0. Every time I launch Aviary action I get a traceback show below for objectAtIndexedSubscript.

I saw this post " [Is objectAtIndexedSubscript available in IOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391169/is-objectatindexedsubscript-available-in-ios5) " and there is no objectAtIndexedSubscript in iOS 5.0. In Aviary documentation it said iOS 5.0 is supported. What did I miss?

So here's my question. Has anyone attempted to incorporate the latest Aviary code build of 2.6.0 for iOS 5.0? If not what Aviary SDK version works for iOS 5.0? Where can I download older version of Aviary SDK. I am just not ready to move to iOS 6.0 yet. I am trying to report this bug to Aviary support but I have feeling they will tell me to go upgrade to iOS 6.0.

From Aviary website:

> Run time requirements The minimum iOS version supported by the SDK is
>   iOS 5.0. The main reasons for this choice are our use of ARC
>   (Automatic Reference Counting) and our reliance on a number of Apple
>   frameworks and libraries which require iOS 5."

```
- (void) launchPhotoEditorWithImage:(UIImage *)editingResImage highResolutionImage:(UIImage *)highResImage
{    

    NSLog(@"launchPhotoEditorWithImage ...");

    // Initialize the photo editor and set its delegate
    AFPhotoEditorController * photoEditor = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:editingResImage];
    [photoEditor setDelegate:self];

    NSLog(@"Present photo editor ...");

    // Present the photo editor.
    [self presentViewController:photoEditor animated:YES completion:nil];
}

2013-03-31 19:32:14.953 Photo Editor[348:707] launchPhotoEditorWithImage ...
2013-03-31 19:32:15.421 Photo Editor[348:707] Present photo editor ...
2013-03-31 19:32:15.421 Photo Editor[348:3f03] -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4ac5f0
2013-03-31 19:32:15.432 Photo Editor[348:3f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4ac5f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x36fbe8bf 0x3232e1e5 0x36fc1acb 0x36fc0945 0x36f1b680 0xb1a45 0x32933d55 0x32935dc7 0x32935c5d 0x32936867 0x37f5c1cf 0x37f5c0a4)
terminate called throwing an exception[Switching to process 9987 thread 0x2703]
[Switching to process 9987 thread 0x2703]
warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.
kill
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
quit
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this guys category (get it from github link) and it will work flawlessly

http://cocoaisland.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/modern-objective-c-part-ii-container-subscripting/

Answer (score 1):

Just update to the newest Xcode. In some old versions of Xcode, `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` is not implemented in the SDK.